# why not display the number of upvotes and downvotes Separately?

Tags: feature-request, votes

###### Update:

I can see the number of upvotes and downvotes now.  The premise is [reputation >= 1000](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

But, I still wonder why to limit this feature to users with reputation below 1000.

---

Say there are 3 answers:

1. one answer got 2 *upvote*s and 1 *downvote*, so, according to the current rule, 
   it will display 1 vote (`=` `number_of_upvotes` `-` `number_of_downvotes`).
2. another answer got 102 *upvote*s and 101 *downvote*s, still, it will display the number 1.
3. the last answer got 102 *upvote*s and 50 *downvote*s, so it will display the number 52.

---

The voting number of the first answer is small probably because it is not on many people's radar, or it is not worth the time to read, etc.

The number of the second answer is small so people may think it is not a mainstream solution and worth about the same as answer number one.  
But the truth is, for 50% of people, it works.

That last answer, though, got a big vote, but it may be unable to solve users' problem because a third of people are still against it but **the website hid/lost the information that how many *downvote*s it got**.

---

Please give users **the right to make their own choices and judgments**, rather than simply losing information (i.e., displaying only the difference number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an opinion site: it's very unlikely that there will be 102 votes for and 101 votes against. That happens in political discourse nowadays, but it *should not happen on a site like Emacs SE*: either the question makes sense, follows the rules, has not been asked before - OR not. That's not a matter of opinion. Either the answer correctly answers the question and/or is useful - OR not. Again, not a matter of opinion.

The 1000 point rule is to prevent people who have no stake in the site from doing damage (either accidental or malicious). It's always possible for somebody to stick around, get 1000 points and *then* do damage, but the vast majority of people are here for the help, not for doing malicious things (and any exceptions can then be handled individually: users *can* be banned by moderators).

Think of it as "getting your driver's license": you need to show that you are responsible enough to "drive" around Emacs SE.

Comment: Why can *the 1000 point rule* prevent people who have no stake in the site from doing damage?

Comment: As I said, it just shows that somebody had enough interest in the site to stick around long enough to get to that point. Please reread what I wrote, starting with "It's always possible ..."

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the number of votes, it will tell you the number of upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: I tried it. To me, that number is just plain text, and nothing happens after I click it. Or you're talking about the privilege of moderators.

Comment: I can see the number of upvotes and downvotes now.  The premise is [reputation >= 1000](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).  Is this rule necessary/reasonable?